# Mocking BsModalRef for Unit Testing

Tags: unit-testing, typescript, karma-jasmine, angular5, ngx-bootstrap

I am using the BsModalRef for showing modals and sending data using the `content` property. So we have some like this :

```
this.followerService.getFollowers(this.bsModalRef.content.channelId).subscribe((followers) => {
    this.followerList = followers;
    this.followerList.forEach((follower) => {
      follower.avatarLink = this.setUserImage(follower.userId);
      this.followerEmails.push(follower.email);
    });
  });
```

We are setting the channelId in content of bsModalRef (`this.bsModalRef.content.channelId`). It is working fine. Now i am writing a unit test for this. Problem is i am not able to mock it. I have tried overriding, spy etc but nothing seems to work. I am using the approach mentioned in this [link](https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/unit-testing/mocks-and-spies/). One alternative is to use TestBed but i am not much aware of its use. Can anyone please help me finding any approach by which this can be achieved ?

Answer (score 8):

I recently had to do something similar and Mocking the method call worked. The tricky part is injecting the BsModalService in both the test suite and the component.

```
describe('MyFollowerService', () => {
    configureTestSuite(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [...],
            declarations: [...],
            providers: [...]
        }).compileComponents();
    });

    // inject the service
    beforeEach(() => {    
        bsModalService = getTestBed().get(BsModalService);
    }


    it('test', () => {
       // Mock the method call 
       bsModalService.show = (): BsModalRef => {
           return {hide: null, content: {channelId: 123}, setClass: null};
       };

       // Do the test that calls the modal

    });
});
```

As long as you're calling bsModal as follows this approach will work

```
let bsModalRef = this.modalService.show(MyChannelModalComponent));
```

Finally, here are some links that have more indepth coverage about setting up the tests with TestBed.

- https://chariotsolutions.com/blog/post/testing-angular-2-0-x-services-http-jasmine-karma/
- http://angulartestingquickstart.com/
- https://angular.io/guide/testing